# Cluster in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am new to ActiveMQ Artemis,

I am trying to understand symmetric-cluster in ActiveMQ Artemis.

[Here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/clustered/symmetric-cluster) is example of it which i am trying to understand.

I am getting the list of Topic message and Queue message which are consume from cluster node, How can i get the information about node means which node is returning this information(Queue message/Topic message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artemis doesn't add any meta-data to the message to indicate which cluster node it's coming from.  Typically a cluster is comprised of interchangeable/indistinguishable nodes so it doesn't actually matter where the message comes from.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, If this is not possible then how we know, how many nodes are up.

Comment: You can use the management operation "listNetworkTopology" on the ActiveMQServerControl object.  This will return a JSON array with information about the members of the cluster.  You can do this programmatically (see the "jmx" example) or administratively via JConsole or another GUI JMX tool.